# Iterator Efficiency: pointer compare or counter

Tags: c, pointers, optimization

For very simple iterators or iterative loops over a range of memory the following two methods can be used (code in simple C to resemble the underlying machine instructions):

Counter:

```
int a[10]; int *p=a; cnt = 10;
do{ 
    foo(*p++); /* loop action */
    cnt--;
} while( cnt > 0);
```

Pointer:

```
int a[10]; int *p=a; int *stop=a+10;
do{
    foo(*p++); /* loop action */
} while( p < stop);
```

Although the latter version seems to be one instruction less, on most machines that I have in my dated memory there is a "decrement register and jump if not zero" instruction which is about as fast (or even faster) than the pointer compare - on architectures with 64 bit pointers and 32-bit data objects even more so. Which of the two versions will be faster on AMD64 and on ARM/ARM64? Is there a compare-pointer-and-branch-if-less instruction?

Comment: Difficult to say with modern compilers, although instinct suggests the second one is faster, and certainly easier to understand. Try both on your target platform or platforms, and profile the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile your application and see if different loops make a difference.

In modern CPUs the bottleneck is memory access latency, rather then instruction throughput. What often makes a real difference is optimizing memory access to avoid CPU cache misses.

Comment: Well, I am aiming at a set of functions which handle a stream that comes in as packets (from a network), so I think that the cache efficiency isn't all too great anyway, because I can't rely on the network code to reuse the memory that it put its packets before. So what I read is: it hardly matters which version to use?

Comment: @Vroomfondel Well, only benchmarking can answer that. I have seen a lot of code that does not benefit from loops with fewer instructions.